# Телеграм бот с автопостингом отказывается работать. Помогите

Tags: python, telegram-bot, бот, telegram

Понадобился бот для автопостинга в ТГ. Логика такая: бот должен брать из папки 4 штуки jpg в алфавитном порядке, класть к  ним строку из txt и публиковать в ТГ с интервалом и расписанием. После этого кропать jpg из исходной в архивную папку и строку тоже кропать со сдвигом вверх из txt и дописывать в архивный. Исход один. Командная строка открывает .py и молчит. Не ругается. Публикаций в канале не происходит. Токен, ID, пути перепроверены. Оба txt, тестовые строки в одном из них и папки созданы. Бот в канал добавлен, правами наделён. Код раза 3 переписывал. Ни один не начал публиковать посты. Уже даже не знаю какой из вариантов лучше. Подскажите, куда копать?   pyTelegramBotAPI==4.12.0 \ Python 3.10.6

**Попытка №1**

```
import os
import telebot
import schedule
import random
import time
import datetime


TOKEN = 'изменёт'
CHANNEL_ID = '-10019196321'
IMAGES_FOLDER = 'C:/Users/eremi/Desktop/BOT_TELEGA/out/out'
TEXT_FILE = 'C:/Users/eremi/Desktop/BOT_TELEGA/out/message.txt'
PUBLISHED_TEXT_FILE = 'C:/Users/eremi/Desktop/BOT_TELEGA/out/message_archive.txt'
ARCHIVE_FOLDER = 'C:/Users/eremi/Desktop/BOT_TELEGA/out/out_archive'

bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

def get_next_image():
    files = sorted(os.listdir(IMAGES_FOLDER))
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.jpg') or file.endswith('.png'):
            return file
    return None

def use_next_text():
    with open(TEXT_FILE, 'r') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        if lines:
            next_line = lines[0].strip()
            lines = lines[1:]
        else:
            next_line = None

    with open(TEXT_FILE, 'w') as file:
        file.writelines(lines)

    with open(PUBLISHED_TEXT_FILE, 'a') as file:
        file.write(next_line + '\n')

    return next_line

def publish_images():
    for _ in range(4):
        image = get_next_image()
        if image is not None:
            caption = use_next_text()
            with open(os.path.join(IMAGES_FOLDER, image), 'rb') as photo:
                bot.send_photo(CHANNEL_ID, photo, caption=caption)
            os.rename(os.path.join(IMAGES_FOLDER, image), os.path.join(ARCHIVE_FOLDER, image))
        else:
            break
    schedule_next_publish()

def schedule_next_publish():
    interval = random.randint(120, 150)
    schedule.every(interval).seconds.do(publish_images)

def check_and_publish():
    now = time.localtime()
    hour = now.tm_hour
    if 10 <= hour < 23:  # Публикация только с 10:00 до 23:00
        publish_images()
    schedule_next_check()

def schedule_next_check():
    # Расписание для следующей проверки времени
    schedule.every().hour.at(':00').do(check_and_publish)

schedule_next_check()

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

**Попытка №2**

```
import os
import telebot
import schedule
import random
import time
import datetime


TOKEN = 'изменён'
CHANNEL_ID = '-изменён'
IMAGES_FOLDER = 'C:/Users/eremi/Desktop/BOT_TELEGA/out/out'
TEXT_FILE = 'C:/Users/eremi/Desktop/BOT_TELEGA/out/message.txt'
PUBLISHED_TEXT_FILE = 'C:/Users/eremi/Desktop/BOT_TELEGA/out/message_archive.txt'
ARCHIVE_FOLDER = 'C:/Users/eremi/Desktop/BOT_TELEGA/out/out_archive'

bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

def get_next_image():
    files = sorted(os.listdir(IMAGES_FOLDER))
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.jpg') or file.endswith('.png'):
            return file
    return None

def use_next_text():
    with open(TEXT_FILE, 'r') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        if lines:
            next_line = lines[0].strip()
            lines = lines[1:]
        else:
            next_line = None

    with open(TEXT_FILE, 'w') as file:
        file.writelines(lines)

    with open(PUBLISHED_TEXT_FILE, 'a') as file:
        file.write(next_line + '\n')

    return next_line

def publish_images():
    print("Publishing images...")
    for _ in range(4):
        image = get_next_image()
        if image is not None:
            caption = use_next_text()
            print("Publishing image:", image)
            print("Caption:", caption)
            with open(os.path.join(IMAGES_FOLDER, image), 'rb') as photo:
                bot.send_photo(CHANNEL_ID, photo, caption=caption)
            os.rename(os.path.join(IMAGES_FOLDER, image), os.path.join(ARCHIVE_FOLDER, image))
            print("Image moved to archive:", image)
        else:
            break
    schedule_next_publish()

def schedule_next_publish():
    interval = random.randint(120, 150)
    print("Scheduling next publish in", interval, "seconds.")
    schedule.every(interval).seconds.do(publish_images)

def check_and_publish():
    now = time.localtime()
    hour = now.tm_hour
    if 10 <= hour < 23:  # Публикация только с 10:00 до 23:00
        publish_images()
    schedule_next_check()

def schedule_next_check():
    # Расписание для следующей проверки времени
    schedule.every().hour.at(':00').do(check_and_publish)

schedule_next_check()

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Он не отказывается, он даже хочет, но не может.

Answer (score 0):

- Вызови просто публикацию без планировщика.
- Поменяй ид канала на свой ид чтобы ты получил в чате бота сообщение.

Если ты получил в обоих случаях значит неправильный ид канала или настройки бота смотри в BotFather

Такойже есть бот и для запсука по расписанию использую:

```
start_times = ['08:15', '15:55', '11:30', '17:55', '19:55']

for times in start_times:
    schedule.every().day.at(times).do(send_message,send_chat_id=f'{send_chat_id}')
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Так в конце функции «get_next_image()» стоит «return None». Может, в этом трабл?

Ибо далее идёт:

```
if image is not None:
   ...
else:
    break
```

Когда функция получает «None» на возврате - ничего, соответственно, и не происходит.